# Safari reader for single page apps?

Tags: html, ajax, layout, safari, mobile-safari

We have a [news website](https://meduza.io).

We'd like to have safari reader feature supported, but we can't get it work, being our website single page app.

I think this could be related to the [ajax + screen readers](http://juicystudio.com/article/making-ajax-work-with-screen-readers.php) issue (for visually impaired).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Googling does not help, all the links are about getting reader feature work for static html, not for a single page app.

Comment: Probably this is better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GáborBakos, I doubt it, this is totally a programmatic question, not about choosing software.

Comment: Sorry, I had the impression you are looking for a lib to achieve this. (Downvote is not from me though.)

Comment: @GáborBakos even if the answer would be a some sort of a software library, it's still a question about programming.

Comment: Off-topic. http://superuser.com/questions/387572/how-does-safaris-reader-work-and-when-does-it-show-up

Comment: @Pinal, looks like you misundestood question. It's very specific — i want to turn safari reader on for a webpage, which is built in the browser runtime via javascript. No info in the web about that, as far as I know